# Unity 2d platformer game: I have a problem in my code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the code so the cube (which is a 2d object) jump if its on the ground here's the code do u know how I tried other ways but they didn't work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercontroler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int thrust = 5;
    public bool OnGround;
    Rigidbody2D Rigidbody;
    public float Speed = 7;

    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            this.transform.position += Vector3.right * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            this.transform.position += Vector3.left * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Rigidbody.velocity = transform.up * thrust;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hit space, Add this line for a jump:

Rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 50, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);

Answer (score 0):

For your information, I use this line of code :

**Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * yourValue);**